# What are the numbers on the status page of Careers.stackoverflow?

Tags: support, jobs, statistics

I recently signed up with careers.stackoverflow and after I paid my membership, setup my CV, filed it and publicly published it, I see some numbers (I assume some statistics) on the Status page:

Some of them are self explanatory, but others are a bit ambiguous.

- 12 Employers

  - Does this mean there are 12 employers on careers.stackoverflow?
  - have 12 employers viewed my CV?

The rest seem related to my profile, as in "the amount of views my public CV has had" etc, it's just this employer one that has me stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean there are 12 employers on careers.stackoverflow?

Yes, it's just a total count of subscribed employers at the moment. We'll be fleshing this out over the next week in a big way.

Answer (score 0):

it was 15 now its 12.
are these beta testing employers?
These odds dont seem favorable